# Solve for x, when $ \log_3 (2 - 3x) = \log_9 (6x^2 - 19x + 2)$

Tags: logarithms

How do you deal with the different bases when solving the equation:

$$\log_3 (2 - 3x) = \log_9 (6x^2 - 19x + 2)$$

I'm going round in circles trying to reconcile the bases.

Comment: **Hint:** $a=b\Leftrightarrow 9^a=9^b$.

Comment: Hint: $\log_3 a = \frac{1}{2}\log_9 a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise both sides to the $9$th power to get:

$$ 9^{\log_3(2 - 3x)} = 9^{\log_9 (6x^2 - 19x + 2)} $$

$$ (3^2)^{\log_3(2 - 3x)} = 6x^2 - 19x + 2 $$
$$ (3^{\log_3(2 - 3x)})^2 = 6x^2 - 19x + 2 $$
$$ (2-3x)^2 = 6x^2 - 19x + 2$$

This is a quadratic in $x$. Solve appropriately.

---

**One last thing** (thanks to Calvin Lin): Keep in mind that in order for the $\log x$ to be defined (over the real numbers), then $x > 0$. After you solve your quadratic, you want to check for extraneous roots. Make sure that your solutions for $x$ satisfy that $ 2 - 3x > 0$ and $ 6x^2 - 19x + 2 > 0 $. (You shouldn't have any problems here, but it's important to do so in general!)

Comment: Should also mention that you need to check the domain, i.e. $2 - 3x > 0$ and $6x^2-19x+2>0$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Let $$\log_3 (2 - 3x) = \log_9 (6x^2 - 19x + 2)=a$$

$\implies 9^a=6x^2 - 19x + 2$ and $3^a=2-3x\implies  9^a=(3^2)^a=(3^a)^2=(2-3x)^2$

So, we have $6x^2 - 19x + 2=(2-3x)^2$

which is a Quadratic Equation of $x$  on re-arrangement